# QSlider Stylesheet According to a Numpy Array

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, pyqt, pyqt5

I have a `numpy` 1d-array where each entry is either 0 or 1. I want to set the sytle sheet of `QSlider` systematically according to this numpy array .

---

Suppose I have a numpy array like this :

```
import numpy as np
myarray = np.array([0,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1]) #len(myarray) = 10
```

I want to construct a `QSlider` with the same length as `myarray` with background blue whenever `myarray` reads 1 and background red whenever `myarray` reads 0. The slider should have no iteraction at all: the user can neither see nor use the handle.

```
slider = QSlider()
slider.setRange(0, len(myarray)-1)
```

But I am stuck afterwards: the command

```
slider.setStyleSheet("QSlider::groove:horizontal {background-color:blue;}")
```

will give a whole blue bar: [image]

What I need is, wherever the array reads 0, it shows red background like this(the picture only paints the first cell to red):[image]

I am not sure about how to change parts of it to red. In my program, `myarray` can be a large array so I probably need a way to programmatically generate a stylesheet, which I don't know how to do.

Comment: So, you want a QSlider that has "chunks" that have different colors for the background, based on the values in the array? For example, considering your second image, that would correspond to an array of `[0, 1, 1, ...lots of 1s..., 1]`?

Comment: Yes exactly. You are understanding it correctly.

Comment: Well, if you want to keep the look of the default handle (including the way it's displayed depending on mouse interaction), that's tricky. If you don't really care about perfect compliance with the default look, that might be *a bit* easier - but still not simple.

Comment: I have just thought about it. I have edited the question. Let us say I don't want the handle to be seen at all: the user is neither able to move the handle nor able to see it. That is, the handle is completely useless.

Comment: So, you don't actually need any interaction at all, and you only want a widget that displays the value range in "chunks"? If that's the case, then that's a completely different story.

Comment: You are right. No interaction at all. But the emphasis is on we have to use QSlider and not anything else. I have edited the question to make that clear.

Comment: Why is that? The whole point of QSlider is to show a range, the current value, and allow user interaction to change that value. If there is no interaction and the handle isn't even shown, using a QSlider is completely meaningless.

Comment: The actual reason are as follows: I really want to display the chunks. In my program, right above the chunk, I decide to put another qslider that is actually working. I need the chunks because this serves as an indication to the actual slider right above it. I choose a qslider for chunk because the chunk and the slider above will be closely aligned. So, if what I am asking is indeed too difficult and there is another way to have a chunk and to have the chunk closely aligned with a slider, I will also accept the answer.

Comment: If what I am asking is still difficult, can you tell me what syntax is needed to change one location of the `qslider`. That is, say `myarray = array([1,1,1,...,0,1,1,1...])` with exactly one 0. In this way, I only need to set blue as background and change the color to red at exactly one location. I do not even know how to do that.

Comment: You can connect the `valueChanged` signal of the slider to a function that sets the stylesheet. Note that you should *always* call that function at startup, because the `0` value might be at the beginning of the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This cannot be achieved using style sheets, as there is no way to set a different background for each "chunk" of the slider.

The only way to properly "colorize" each value is by using QStyle features. Specifically, we need to use [`sliderPositionFromValue`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstyle.html#sliderPositionFromValue), which returns the position in pixel for each value.

Since we can assume that all values are equally spread across the slider, we can create "ranges" that split each pair of "ticks" in half based on the full range count.

For instance, if we have a slider length (the space in which the handle can move) of 100 pixels and the slider has 5 values (from 0 to 4), we will have 5 chunks, each 25 pixels wide, with the first one starting ~12 pixels on the left of the slider position at `0`.

For optimization reasons (and to avoid graphic issues of same-color rectangles that are side by side), we only draw rectangles that join similar values.

Here is the result:

[image: Screenshot of the result]

And the code (note that I added ticks to the slider to highlight the alignment of the chunks):

```py
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *


class SliderChunkWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, slider, values):
        super().__init__()
        self.slider = slider
        self.values = values
        self.setFixedHeight(self.fontMetrics().height())

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        opt = QStyleOptionSlider()
        self.slider.initStyleOption(opt)

        style = self.slider.style()

        # get the extent of the slider handle
        sliderLength = style.pixelMetric(style.PM_SliderLength, opt, self.slider)
        offset = sliderLength // 2
        # the actual space in which the handle can move
        avail = opt.rect.width() - sliderLength

        smin = self.slider.minimum()
        smax = self.slider.maximum()
        # get the position of the first value of the slider
        start = style.sliderPositionFromValue(
            smin, smax, smin, avail) + offset

        # the size of each "chunk"
        chunkSize = avail / (len(self.values) - 1)
        x = start - chunkSize / 2
        chunks = 1
        height = self.height() - 1

        qp = QPainter(self)
        qp.setRenderHint(qp.Antialiasing)
        qp.setPen(Qt.NoPen)

        oldValue = self.values[0]
        for value in self.values[1:]:
            if value != oldValue:
                # the new value is different, draw the previous rectangle
                qp.setBrush(Qt.blue if oldValue else Qt.red)
                rect = QRectF(x, 0, chunks * chunkSize, height)
                qp.drawRect(rect)
                chunks = 1
                x = rect.right()
            else:
                chunks += 1
            oldValue = value

        # draw the last rectangle
        qp.setBrush(Qt.blue if value else Qt.red)
        qp.drawRect(x, 0, chunks * chunkSize, height)


app = QApplication([])
values = [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]

test = QWidget()
layout = QVBoxLayout(test)

slider = QSlider(Qt.Horizontal, maximum=len(values) - 1)
layout.addWidget(slider)
slider.setTickPosition(slider.TicksBothSides)
slider.setTickInterval(1)

chunkWidget = SliderChunkWidget(slider, values)
layout.addWidget(chunkWidget)

test.show()
app.exec()
```